# Scala - Safely get element from multidimensional array

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array, collections

```
val arr = Array.fill[String](6, 6)("dark")
```

Unsafe get:

```
 arr(9)(9)
>java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
```

I use something like that (but ugly):

```
arr.lift(2).flatMap(_.lift(2))

>res0: Option[String] = Some(dark)
```

Is there better way?

Comment: Define a `safeGet[T](x:Int, y:Int):Option[T]`, using whatever code you like (an explicit array-bounds check might be clearest), then make it an implicit operation on Array. Then the ugliness is just in one place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

```
val arr = Array.fill[String](6, 6)("dark")

implicit class SafeArrayOps[T](arr: Array[Array[T]]) {
  def safeGet(x: Int, y: Int) = {
    if (x < 0 || x >= arr.length) None
    else {
      val inner = arr(x)
      if (y <= 0 || y >= inner.length) None
      else Some(inner(y))
    }
  }
}

arr.safeGet(2,2)                                //> res0: Option[String] = Some(dark)
arr.safeGet(7,7)                                //> res1: Option[String] = None
arr.safeGet(2,7)                                //> res2: Option[String] = None
arr.safeGet(7,2)                                //> res3: Option[String] = None
arr.safeGet(-1, 2)                              //> res4: Option[String] = None
arr.safeGet(2,-1)                               //> res5: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Brilliant! Combining it with @sascha-kolberg answer it looks even better, I think.

Comment: I'm not too bothered about how it looks. I subscribe to the advice of http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-Programming-Style-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0070342075 "Say what you mean simply and directly".

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I am too bothered about how it looks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something more readable, you could use a for comprehension:

```
for {
 inner <- arr.lift(7)
 value <- inner.lift(2)
} yield value
```